# CircleImageView crop my profile picture

Tags: android

I am testing CircleImageView class to make circle to my profile picture but actually it crops my profile picture. All i want to see my whole profile picture in that Circular

```
public class CircleImageView extends ImageView {

    private static final ScaleType SCALE_TYPE = ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;

    private static final Bitmap.Config BITMAP_CONFIG = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    private static final int COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION = 2;

    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0;
    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;

    private final RectF mDrawableRect = new RectF();
    private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();

    private final Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();
    private final Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mBorderPaint = new Paint();

    private int mBorderColor = DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR;
    private int mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private int mBitmapWidth;
    private int mBitmapHeight;

    private float mDrawableRadius;
    private float mBorderRadius;

    private ColorFilter mColorFilter;

    private boolean mReady;
    private boolean mSetupPending;

    public CircleImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleImageView, defStyle, 0);

        mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CircleImageView_border_width, DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH);
        mBorderColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_border_color, DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
        a.recycle();
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        super.setScaleType(SCALE_TYPE);
        mReady = true;

        if (mSetupPending) {
            setup();
            mSetupPending = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ScaleType getScaleType() {
        return SCALE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
        if (scaleType != SCALE_TYPE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("ScaleType %s not supported.", scaleType));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdjustViewBounds(boolean adjustViewBounds) {
        if (adjustViewBounds) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("adjustViewBounds not supported.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (getDrawable() == null) {
            return;
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, mDrawableRadius, mBitmapPaint);
        if (mBorderWidth != 0) {
            canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, mBorderRadius, mBorderPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        setup();
    }

    public int getBorderColor() {
        return mBorderColor;
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
        if (borderColor == mBorderColor) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderColor = borderColor;
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getBorderWidth() {
        return mBorderWidth;
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
        if (borderWidth == mBorderWidth) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderWidth = borderWidth;
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        mBitmap = bm;
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable);
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageResource(int resId) {
        super.setImageResource(resId);
        mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable());
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
        super.setImageURI(uri);
        mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable());
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        if (cf == mColorFilter) {
            return;
        }

        mColorFilter = cf;
        mBitmapPaint.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
        invalidate();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap;

            if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, BITMAP_CONFIG);
            } else {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), BITMAP_CONFIG);
            }

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            drawable.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void setup() {
        if (!mReady) {
            mSetupPending = true;
            return;
        }

        if (mBitmap == null) {
            return;
        }

        mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBitmapPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

        mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);

        mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
        mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();

        mBorderRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        mBorderRadius = Math.min((mBorderRect.height() - mBorderWidth) / 2, (mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth) / 2);

        mDrawableRect.set(mBorderWidth, mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.height() - mBorderWidth);
        mDrawableRadius = Math.min(mDrawableRect.height() / 2, mDrawableRect.width() / 2);

        updateShaderMatrix();
        invalidate();
    }

    private void updateShaderMatrix() {
        float scale;
        float dx = 0;
        float dy = 0;

        mShaderMatrix.set(null);

        if (mBitmapWidth * mDrawableRect.height() > mDrawableRect.width() * mBitmapHeight) {
            scale = mDrawableRect.height() / (float) mBitmapHeight;
            dx = (mDrawableRect.width() - mBitmapWidth * scale) * 0.5f;
        } else {
            scale = mDrawableRect.width() / (float) mBitmapWidth;
            dy = (mDrawableRect.height() - mBitmapHeight * scale) * 0.5f;
        }

        mShaderMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        mShaderMatrix.postTranslate((int) (dx + 0.5f) + mBorderWidth, (int) (dy + 0.5f) + mBorderWidth);

        mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);
    }

}
```

Please tell me where i exactly do the change to see my whole image in that CircularImageView.

Comment: Damn son! Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: How can someone be so lazy? You want help? Then work for it and provide an example that fits the comment above...

Comment: If you fit your square image into circular than may be it doesn't look better. So using this cropping is better.

Comment: @kibzorg ,but i saw some layouts in which my whole profile pic is fit.

Comment: @ulhas, may be you are seeing layout with clipped images from corner. I have code to make bitmap only circular but it also clips bitmap to show it rounded. see answer for code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

    public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b =  ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() ;
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();


        Bitmap roundBitmap =  getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0, null);

    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sbmp;
        if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
            sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
        else
            sbmp = bmp;
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
                sbmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xffa19774;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
                sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);


        return output;
    }

}
```

And here is the xml view.

```
<your_package.RoundedImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the circularImageView [Library](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView) :

sample code:

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    app:border="true"
    app:border_color="@color/GrayLight"
    app:border_width="4dp"
    app:shadow="true" />
```

[image]

Comment: i use same library but it make circle at center and crop other view of that picture.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get circular bitmap of image and than set it to normal imageView.

Pass your image bitmap and your desired radius of circular view.

```
public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sbmp;
        if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
            sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
        else
            sbmp = bmp;
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight(),
                Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

//      final int color = 0xffa19774;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f,
                sbmp.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f, sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: your code is work for me but i think it has some pixel issue.
My profile pictures pixels not looking so good.
@kibzorg

Comment: try to pass bitmap's width/height to radius